Why Does AnnotatedString.fromHtml() Fail to Apply Link Styles Correctly?
val htmlText =
"This is an example with inline links and HTML formatting."
val annotatedString = AnnotatedString.fromHtml(htmlText)
BasicText(text = annotatedString)
Here's the result failure to apply linkstyle
I’m encountering an issue where AnnotatedString.fromHtml() does not apply link styles as expected. I’m not sure if this is related to the problem highlighted on the official page.
Note this Saver doesn't preserve the LinkInteractionListener of the links. You should handle this case manually if required (check https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/332901550 for an example)
I manually applied linkStyle, and here is the result:
val linkStyle = TextLinkStyles(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.Blue))
enter image description here
It was in the latest beta06 version, suggest potential solutions?
I expected the result to automatically apply link styles without needing manual.

It is expected behavior. If you need to style your links, you can pass your style as the second parameter to fromHtml(annotatedString, linkStyle).

It is possible to apply style for links. Please try this one
AnnotatedString.fromHtml(
                        htmlString = "HTML here",
                        linkStyles = TextLinkStyles(
                            style = SpanStyle(
                                textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline,
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                            )
                        ),

